# loading a bitmap to the "right" size

Tags: android, bitmap

i want to load a bitmap off the SD card and display it.  the image on the SD card is 2592x1728, and i want to display this image in a 200x200 pixel image.  when i load the image, obviously, I don't want to load the entire image into memory (2592x1728x3 bytes!).  is there a way to automatically load it into the right size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this snippet. Its about as good as it gets. You will have to read over the whole image at least once, but you can scale it down to a `Bitmap` object that is a little bit less cumbersome to work with.

[Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue/823966#823966)